# How to set the variable to true or false based on the length using ternary operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array named `currentOrders`.

if its length is 1 then I want to set the variable output to true if not false using javascript.

I writing something like this using ternary operator

```
const isOneOrder = currentOrders.length === 1 ? true : false;
```

I think the above can be rewritten still more good. but i am not sure how it can be rewritten.

How can I rewrite this. could someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: Side note: It's called the *conditional* operator. It's *a* ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands), just like `*` is a binary operator (an operator accepting two operands). And it happens that for the moment, it's JavaScript's only ternary operator. But that could change. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you can write like this.

```
const isOneOrder = currentOrders.length === 1;
```

`===` operator will return `true` if value and type are same and will return `false` in othercases.

Therefore, no need to define `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

you could write it like this

```
const isOneOrder = !!currentOrders.length;
```

when you add two `!!` it will convert the value to boolean

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove the ternary operator:

```js
let currentOrders = [1];
const isOneOrder = currentOrders.length === 1;
console.log(isOneOrder);
currentOrders = [1, 2];
const isNotOneOrder = currentOrders.length === 1;
console.log(isNotOneOrder);
```